# OnScroll Navbar modify in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a student in university and wondering about what is the best solution for this use case that I'm wanting to use on a project:

Standard `navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed` div  with a `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` div inside it. that has a logotype in left hand side http://www.bootply.com/8PW9UzYPOo

which on scroll is replaced with a `navbar-brand` element that contains the words of the logotype  http://www.bootply.com/Q3NXBLXWBN.

I think somehow that javascript would be the solution, but I'm not sure.

---

Pseudo code

```
If scroll beyond x pixels
hide logotype <a> link
replace with text <a> link
text as class="navbar-brand"
```

---

An example I've seen on another site, but it's a module of Drupal on this [example](https://gfycat.com/UntriedPassionateAoudad) and the logo simply disappears rather than being replaced.

Comment: find on google there are lots of ready made code for this

Comment: there's a bit many options, so wanted more a recommendation on which is the most stable.

also not sure exactly what terms to search.

Comment: see this example http://jsfiddle.net/gxRC9/501/

Comment: just remove logo when class added for example .sticky .logo {display:none}

Comment: that doesn't answer how to remove the image and replace with text though.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/p3KI16wQB4 see this

Comment: Thanks,  you may as well turn the comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add class on your element and than play with it

for example

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.navbar-fixed-top'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) sticky.addClass('fixed');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

and than play with that class

```
.logo-text {
    display:none;
}
.fixed .logo-text {
    display:block;
}
.fixed .logo-img {
    display:none;
}
```

**[working example](http://www.bootply.com/p3KI16wQB4)**

Comment: One thing though,  navbar-brand doesn't play well with images,  so it would be better to add that at same time as fixed.  How would go about that?

Comment: .logo-img >img {// your css here}